# PHP Function pulling an array that matches the parameter

Tags: php, arrays, global-variables

```
$youtubes = array("lNT4H39G2rw","pF2_qvdm8DQ","_8ytwhhJwco","K16ZRFWR2Mc","9WuPxe7zc6Q","rXZIIclPnd0","J8ZwyN6E3_Q","OEWJbsh0z-4","o62-X0stdFM","aIIiww2Neq0","5TJc-VbNYg0","MYQa1Tgw_z8","alxzFm-bqug","UmI7oyllrlY","RGKFXDHFmn4");

function randomFromArray($data) {
    global $$data;
    echo $$data[rand(0,count($youtubes)-1)];
}

randomFromArray("youtubes");
```

I am trying to get this to work as a function, so I can enter the array name as a parameter. It is then supposed to echo a random entry from the array. The bit where it gets the random entry from array works on its own if I substitute it straight in, but I can't seem to get it working as a function.

Any help?

Comment: Please clarify: are you asking about the `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO, expecting ',' or ';'` error your current code triggers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dont call the function randomFromArray("youtubes"); in this way you call the function with youtubes parametar like a string. and inside the function itself you dont have a $youtubes variable. call the function like this randomFromArray($youtubes);
hope this would help

Answer (score 2):

You're using the variable name `$youtubes` in your `randomFromArray` function in the call to `count` (but the variable is not available under that name there).

Btw., why don't you pass in (a reference to) the array instead of its name? Would be much tidier than using `global $$data`; The following code uses a reference to avoid copying the array (but remember that then, the outside array could be changed from inside the method):

```
$youtubes = // ...

function randomFromArray(&$data) {
    echo $data[rand(0,count($data)-1)];
}

randomFromArray($youtubes);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the string 'youtubes' into the function, not the array. You want to pass in the name of the array:

```
randomFromArray($youtubes);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$youtubes = array("lNT4H39G2rw","pF2_qvdm8DQ","_8ytwhhJwco","K16ZRFWR2Mc","9WuPxe7zc6Q","rXZIIclPnd0","J8ZwyN6E3_Q","OEWJbsh0z-4","o62-X0stdFM","aIIiww2Neq0","5TJc-VbNYg0","MYQa1Tgw_z8","alxzFm-bqug","UmI7oyllrlY","RGKFXDHFmn4"); 

function randomFromArray($data) { 
    echo $data[rand(0,count($data)-1)]; 
} 

randomFromArray($youtubes);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some things fundamentally wrong here.

`global $$data`
Why is there a double $ sign? And where would this data be coming from?

`echo $$data[rand(0,count($youtubes)-1)];`
Your function doesn't know the variable $youtubes, since you have never defined it inside of the function. All your function knows is the `$data` variable that you are passing to it.

`randomFromArray("youtubes");` You are passing a string to your function, rather then your array. You probably want this instead:

```
randomFromArray($youtubes); // Pointing to your actual array, rather then a string
```

Try reading up on [PHP functions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php) first before attempting to use them as you're lacking a lot of basic knowledge about them.

Comment: In certain situations you can use names like he wants to use, and that doesn't imply a lack in his knowledge.

Comment: Apologies; It didn't occur to me that variables could be used as parameters. I would have thought the variable would contain nothing and therefore the function be 'randomFromArray()". Why isn't it like this? What if $youtubes did happen to be previously defined as say '2', it would then pass as 'randomFromArray(2)". This is why I used randomFromArray("youtubes"), and then the double $ to change it into a variable (as it was already a variable b/c it was a parameter). Also, why didn't I have to use global as the array was not apart of the function?

Answer (score 0):

After you put a `;` after `global $$data`, you can try this: `$f = $$data;` and then `echo $f[rand(..)];` if you really want to use names instead variables as others suggested. And if you do that you can use the string  (or $f) further in the function code.